# Schedule job iteration after current iteration completes in spring

Tags: java, spring, scheduler

I have the requirement as follows

I have to run a job on every day at 01:00 AM.So I used following cron expression for that

```
  0 00 01 * * ?
```

But some times the job is taking more than 24 hours.If the job not completed with in 1 day, next iteration(next day) is not executing .

So I want to change the implementation as follows.

After completing the iteration by taking some specified interval time next iteration should be started.How to configure that configuration ?.Is it possible using spring?

If I mention repeatInterval , it will execute as my previous configuration.Any other solutions are there by using spring job scheduler.